# Qt library path incorrect in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, path, qt-creator

I have a project, initially created in Visual Studio using Qt Add-In, which I now converted to use QMake (after generating Qt project file). It works fine in VS, however trying to build it in Qt Creator results in:

```
:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2010_openglC:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Networkd.lib'
```

You can see that the path to Qt is repeated twice and so the library cannot be found. Any clues on what may be causing it?

Comment: Can we see your .pro file?

Comment: I agree with Mitch. In addition, can you try in console for a bit without QtCreator to see if you get it right?

Comment: The pro file is pretty big as it is a large project and it does seem to work in VS. By looking at the Makefile I have now identified the problem to be with a QtFtp library. For some reason the paths in qtftp prl files were set like that. I've edited them manually at everything builds now. No idea what might have caused the problem in the first place though.

Comment: This issue is mysterious so far... Either way, a self-contained project file with a little code that demonstrating the issue should be sufficient.